# Weird Java Syntax

Tags: java, syntax

I was doing a practice Computer Science UIL test form when I came across this problem:

What is output by the following?

```
int a = 5;
int b = 7;
int c = 10;
c = b+++-c--+--a;
System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
```

I put down the answer "No output due to syntax error" but I got it wrong.  The real answer was 4 8 1! (I tested it out myself)

Can someone please explain to me how line 4 works?
Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand your question...

Comment: I don't understand what is going on in line 4.  How can you have (b+++-c) without that being a syntax error??

Comment: @JohnDoe:  Quite easily, actually.

Comment: @JohnDoe Have a look at my answer, it explains it.

Comment: I'm sorry you had to deal with such a terrible question on a test. If I ever encountered an equation like this in the field I'd immediately rewrite it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I added some parentheses:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 7;
int c = 10;
c = (b++) + (-(c--)) + (--a);
System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
```

**b++ :**
b = b + 1 after b is used

**c-- :**
c = c - 1 after c is used

**--a :**
a = a - 1 before a is used

Answer (score 6):

Look at it like this:

```
(b++) + (-(c--)) + (--a)
```

That should make more sense!

Look at [Operator Precedence](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) to see why it works this way.

Answer (score 3):

Look at initialization of `c` like this, `c = (b++) + (-(c--)) + (--a);`

They had it compressed and intentionally confusing for your learning purposes. The code is essentially saying this, `c = (b + 1) + (-(c - 1)) + (a - 1);`

Answer (score 2):

Break up the statement a bit.  It's intentionally obfuscated.

```
c = b++ + -c-- + --a;
```

What this means:

- The variable `c` is assigned the result of...

  - `b` (incrementation will take effect after this line), plus
  - the unary operation `-` of `c` (decrementation will take effect after this line), plus
  - `a` (decrementation takes immediate effect).

Replace the variables with the values, and you get:

```
c = 7 + (-10) + 4
c = 1
```

...and the result of your print statement should be:

```
4 8 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's slow down, and look hard at the equation. Think about this carefully.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 7; 
int c = 10;
c = b+++-c--+--a;
```

b++ means increment b after assignment, so b stays equal to its original value in the equation, but will be incremented afterward the equation.

Then there's a +.

Then a negated `c--`. `c` gets decremented but will remain the same for the equation.

Then add that to --a, which means a gets decremented immediately.

So the variables values at the print statement will be:

```
c = 7 + -10 + 4 = 1
a = 4
b = 8
```

May I add that in my opinion this is a bad question for a test. All its really asking is if you understand `i++` vs `++i`.