# Java: Difference between +--i and +++i

Tags: java, operators, operator-precedence

Last day while programming, I mistakenly wrote something like this-

```
int i = 2;
int j = 3;
int a = i+++j;
```

And it did not shoot any error and I got-

> a = 5

After detecting this coding error I was curious. So, I started playing with it. When I changed it a little-

```
int a = i+ ++j;
```

I got-

> a = 6

With this-

```
int a = i+ + +j;
```

and this-

```
int a = i++ +j;
```

I again got-

> a = 5

**Similar situation was experienced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039908/weird-java-syntax)**.

But here comes the weird part. There is no difference between `a = i+--j` & `a = i+ --j`. Both gives-

> a = 4

Why is that? I completely understand what exactly is happening here. The thing I do not understand is- **'WHY?'**. `+` and `-` are both operators, then why there is a difference?

---

For clarity, I wish to share another odd experience. This code works perfectly-

```
int i=0;
System.out.println("value: "+--i);
```

And outputs-

> value: -1

But this-

```
System.out.println("value: "+++i);
```

Gives following error-

> error: unexpected type

Comment: What you would want  is [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) of Java which will explain everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bunti pointed out, your answer is in the [**Operator Precedence**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

When you do,

```
int a = i+++j;
```

It's evaluated as `int a = (i++) + j` since Postfix has the highest precedence.
Now you know why you get `a = 5` there. *Print `i` along with `a` and you will see it's incremented.*

Similarly, when you do `System.out.println("value: "+++i);`, it's evaluated to `System.out.println(("value: "++) + i);`

But postfix operations are not applicable to String. Hence the syntax error.

But when you do, `System.out.println("value: "+--i);`, this is evaluated to `System.out.println("value: "+ (--i));`. Hence it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Operator precedence is only half of the answer, since the first thing to clarify is what the operators in your code are.

*Basically* `i+++j` could be interpreted as `i ++ + j`, as `i + ++ j` or as `i + + + j`.

**However** according to the lexical rules of Java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2) the interpretation is the same as if the expression was written as `i ++ + j`.

According to the operator precedence this is evaluated is `(i++) + j`, so that in `int a = i++ + j;` `a` is 5 (and `i` is 3!).

For `i+--j` the tokens are `i + -- j` (since the is no operator `+-`), which is according to operator precedence `i + (--j)`, so that in `int a = i + --j;` `a` is 4 (and `j` is now 2).

---

Now comes the fun part:

What is `int a = i + + + j;`? This is the same as `int a = i + (+(+j));` (`+j` being the unary plus operation on `j`), so this gives again 5 (but `i` is still 2 and `j` is still 3, which is different from the case `i++ + j`!)

And what is `int a = i + - - j;`? This is the same as `int a = i + (-(-j));` (`-j` being the unary minus operation on `j`) which also gives 5 (and also does not modify `i` or `j`).

What is `int a = i++++j;`? This is not a valid Java expression (it will not compile), since this is equivalent to `(i++) ++ j` and since `i++` cannot be converted to a variable this is illegal (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) and then there is this dangling `j` too.

Adding more `+` without adding spaces does not make it legal, while `i++ + ++j` is perfectly legal...

---

Similarly, `"SomeString"+++i` is illegal, since this is read as `("SomeString"++)+i` and you can't increment a String literal (and also not a String variable).

`"SomeString"+--i` is valid, since this is read as `"SomeString"+(--i)`, which appends the result of `--i` to "SomeString".

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answers the behavior of arithmetic operation-

```
int i = 2;
int j = 3;
int a = i+++j;
```

a=5 as there is no space between the `+` symbol. Even if you put any more `+` symbols in between, the answer will remain the same. To explain its working, it is similar to any basic calculator we use, if i input a number and type `+`  for any number of times, the second input when received will still give the sum of the 2 input-ed numbers. This is because the compiler is initializing the addition operation between the 2 numbers.

```
int a = i+ ++j;
```

Here in this case, you are adding the `i` to the incremented value of `j`. So it is like u are looking for an operation of `2+ ++3`, which is `2+4` and hence the answer `6`. the `++` operator is defined as an increment in the **JRE**.

```
int a = i+ + +j;
```

Here it behaves same as the 1st case as `+j` or `i+` are not increment operators defined by JRE.

```
int a = i+--j;
```

In this interesting case, we are using 2 diff arithmetic operators i.e. `+` and `--`. As `--` is defined, the decrement of `j` value happens and the change value of `j` is added to `i`.

```
int a = i+ --j;
```

As in above, since `+` and `-` are diff operations. the space between them or not doesn't matter.

```
int i=0;
System.out.println("value: "+--i);
```

In this case, we are printing a string and using `+--i`; so **JRE** treats it as printing out Value: decrement of `i`. As known in print statement, `+` is used to make system print multiple value at a time.

```
System.out.println("value: "+++i);
```

coming to this, the `+` in print function is defined to provide a way to print several variable that are separated by a `+` symbol and hence the conjunction of `+++` is not defined for print function and hence gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

Many of them have written answers for this. I would like to put it in different words.

`i++` is post fix.

In post fix operation, value is incremented after the value is extracted.

Thus in case of `i+++j`, we have original value of `i` when expression is evaluated, and `i` is incremented after the evaluation is completed.

In case of `++j` since its prefix value is incremented before evaluation.

This `i+++j` is equal to `(i++)+j` and `i+ ++j` is equivalent to `i + (++j)`.

Hope this adds this helps adding to your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

May be the `i+++j` just is `i+j`, but the `i+ ++j` is `i + ++j`, there `++j` change's , 'j=4'. So `i[2] + j[4] = 6`.

Java May not recognize three `+++`.